# Dual Health-bar in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have been looking around and there isn't much on this topic. I'm currently trying to make a dual health bar where if one is low the other rises, similar to a struggle system.

Like this:

[image]

So far I have created two 2d sliders in unity one with left to right anchor (the red one) and the other with a right to left anchor, however one is overlapped and and doesn't go below its original length but can go higher, I have tried changing the min and max values but this doesn't help.

[image]

How can I get it to become lower but at the same time make the other slider rise?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class healthbar : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider slider;

    public void SetHealth(int health)
    {
        slider.value = health;
    }
}
```

This is my script for the red bar so far.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need 2 health bars, you can cheat instead.

You can use just one red health bar with a green background.

the slider value being the ratio red/green

```
// note that both RedHealth and GreenHealth should be float
slider.value = RedHealth / (RedHealth + GreenHealth);
```

Comment: i did what you said but it doesnt change size, it only changes through slider and doesnt decrease from its original just increases

Comment: @Hamza It is not supposed to change size. Cid is using a single slider with a background of one color and the fill is the other. As the health of one goes up, the other appears to go down as the fill increases meaning the background shown decreases. I would also recommend using an [`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) with horizontal fill instead of a slider, as a slider is able to be modified by player input.